# Upgrading ARM64 support, Theos compiles but doesn't work, ideas?

Tags: cydia, theos, cydia-substrate

I created a Cydia Tweak and have been trying to update it for arm64 devices but for some reason my testers report the tweak doesn't work.

I've been researching online and figured out adding arm64 support should be as simple as adding arm64 to the ARCHS in the makefile.

The git for the tweak is https://github.com/CPDigitalDarkroom/CC-Deseparator, I've tested like 5 different formats for the Makefile with none of them working for my testers.

I am using the latest version of THEOS so that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your tweak and it works

I've removed armv6 from ARCHS

and changed

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk
```

to:

```
include $(THEOS)/makefiles/common.mk
```

if you still having trouble. make ur tweak again and post your console

Comment: I forgot to come back and close this question, figured out I had an issue with the ARCHS section and compiling on a phone wouldn't work, compiled on Mac and it worked. Thanks though